# Declare variable in sass for color web changer

Tags: variables, sass

i am making color changer for my web, is it possible to make variable like this :

```
.red { $color: red; $background: red; }
.green { $color: green; $background: green; }
.blue { $color: blue; $background: blue; }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your SASS here - at least in principle - but syntatically it's a tad skewed. Also, what your trying to do though requires so client side run-time code for it to be implemented.

First up though you don't actually need the variables - but we'll run with it. So change your sass to

```
$red: #ff1a1a;
$green: #5cd65c;
$blue: #1a75ff;

.blue { background-color: $blue; }
.green { background-color: $green }
.red { background-color: $red }
```

assuming this generates a CSS file and your importing this into your HTML page you'll need a little bit of Javascript to apply the appropriate colour class to the element you want to take on this property.

Assuming you have 3 elements ( buttons ) with unique ID's, which when clicked will change the background colour of an element id=foo you could have something like

```
var changeColor = function(col) {
    document.getElementById("foo").className = col
}

document.getElementById('buttonblue').addEventListener('click', 
 function() {
    changeColor('blue');
 }, false);
 document.getElementById('buttongreen').addEventListener('click', 
 function() {
    changeColor('green');
 }, false);
 // ... etc etc for each color button you have
```

This is far from clean or modularised code, but hopefully it outlines the principle of the process which you need to follow

Here's a working codePen with the example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rewoOY

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what i mean is the variables have same name but different value, and the value is based on class.
because i have a lot of variables for one color themes, and i have to declare a lot of variables again for the other color's themes?

Comment: Ok - in that case _@extend_ is your friend

Comment: ok i will learn more about @extend, thanks pete